# Divergence when calculating moments with a space-time Gaussian white noise

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations, noise, stochastic-pde

Consider a variable $M(x,t)$ driven by space-time Gaussian white noise:
$$ \partial_t M(x,t) = -k M + \xi(x,t).$$
The noise has mean $\langle \xi(x,t) \rangle = 0$ and correlation function $\langle \xi(x,t)\xi(y,s) \rangle = 2D\delta(x-y)\delta(t-s)$.

Supposing the initial condition is $M(x,0) = 0$, one can integrate for the solution given a particular realization of the noise:
$$ M(x,t) = \int_0^t dt_1 e^{-k(t-t_1)}\xi(x,t_1).$$

My goal is to calculate the second moment $\langle M(x,t)^2 \rangle.$
It's (apparently) easy to square the noise and use the correlation function to calculate the second moment:
$$\langle M(x,t)^2 \rangle = \int_0^t dt_1 \int_0^t dt_2 e^{-2kt + k t_1 + k t_2} \langle \xi(x,t_1) \xi(x,t_2)\rangle$$
i.e.
$$ \langle M(x,t)^2 \rangle = \int_0^t dt_1 \int_0^t dt_2 e^{-2kt + k t_1 + k t_2} 2 D \delta(x-x)\delta(t_1-t_2).$$
Yet here, in contrast to the case of when the Gaussian noise only depends on time, one encounters a divergence due to the Dirac delta of $0$:
$$ \langle M(x,t)^2 \rangle = \frac{D}{k} \delta(0) \big( 1- e^{-2kt}\big) \rightarrow \infty.$$

How can such a simple model with symmetric fluctuations and damping generate infinite fluctuations? I found a very similar calculation in the book "Fractal concepts of surface growth" by Barbasi et al (1995). They follow the exact same steps as me without presenting any divergence (in eq. 4.12). They seem to simply set $\delta(0)=1$. What am I missing here?

Comment: Your $M$-process is not going to be function but distribution-valued. Hence you cannot make sense of pointwise evaluations and terms like $M^{2}$. If you want some sort of moment you will need to integrate against some test function, i.e. you may calculate e.g. $\mathbb{E}\langle M_{t},\phi\rangle^{2}$

Comment: Thanks @Tobsn. Can you suggest any resources on this point? Preferably accessible to physicsists? I find it strange the physics literature (particularly the barbasi book referenced) brushes over this point. I'm unclear on when exactly the test function would be applied: should one calculate $G = \int dx \phi(x) M(x,t) $ and then compute any expectations from $G$?

Comment: Yes, exactely. Well, there are tons of lecture notes on SPDEs out there. It is however a demanding subject. I cannot really judge whether some of them are partiularly easy to assess for physicists. A generic starting point might be the notes of Martin Hairer, who happens to a theoretical physicist, originally.